# calling a function in android after intervals?

Tags: android

I would like to call a function `ABC()` every 10 seconds, again and again till I use return statement to quit. But I don't want to use any Java `Time` function.

Anyone can guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

```
 CountDownTimer t = new CountDownTimer( Long.MAX_VALUE , 10000) {

        // This is called every interval. (Every 10 seconds in this example)
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.d("test","Timer tick");
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Log.d("test","Timer last tick");            
            start();
        }
     }.start();
```

Comment: but it is fixed i want to make unlimited calls after each 10 seconds then?