# Calling a method every 10 minutes in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent

I have an activity with a button. When I press that button, a method should be called every 10 minutes.

I am trying to do so using a `Handler` and a `Timer`. But couldn't get the result.

Comment: try using AlrmManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: You can consider the below mentioned links: [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4612602/1627599) [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227335/calling-a-function-in-android-after-intervals) I hope these helps!

Comment: I followed the first link. It worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create a `Timer` object and give it a `TimerTask` that performs the code you'd like to perform.

```
Timer timer = new Timer ();
TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask () {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        // your code here...
    }
};

// schedule the task to run starting now and then every hour...
timer.schedule (hourlyTask, 0l, 1000*60*60);   // 1000*10*60 every 10 minut
```

The advantage of using a Timer object is that it can handle multiple TimerTask objects, each with their own timing, delay, etc. You can also start and stop the timers as long as you hold on to the Timer object by declaring it as a class variable or something.

Comment: @John : can you get your answer ?

Answer (score 3):

use following code and in which notifyme() is called repeated after no of milliseconds you have given as second parameter

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
    {
       public void run()
       {
           View v = new View(getApplicationContext());
           notifyMe(v);
       }},4000,100000);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an [AlamManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) if you don't need your app to be running in the background. Else you can have a Service that is constantly running and a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Answer (score 1):

The [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running.

For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.

Answer (score 1):

**-** Its better to use `Service`, its an `Activity` **withOUT** `View`.

**-** `Service` can be **bounded or unbounded** to the `Activity`.

**See this link for Service example:**

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

**-** But if you still want to go with the Thread, then try this...

**1.** If your `Thread` **(Non-UI)** is **Not posting any data on the Dedicated UI thread, then there is no need to use Handler, but if it does then Handler is must.**

**Eg:**

```
Handler h;    
onCreate() {    
  h = new Handler();
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
      while(true){
        try{
          h.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
              go();
            }
          }
         TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(10);
       }
       catch(Exception ex){
       }
     }
    }
  }).start();
} 
public void go(){
  // This method is called every 10 minutes
}
```

You do this same using something known as `Painless Threading`, known as `AsyncTask`.